# error when include <list> in cocos2d project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i want to include list in cocos2d. the error is : "the file/directory doesn't exist". i've tried to change my file type(xcode4) to objc++ and objc and even c. but still won't work. anyone know how to fix it?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#include <list>

#define POINT_LIMIT 50
#define USE_LAGRANGE 1

using namespace std;

inline float lagrange2(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, CGPoint p3, float x);
inline float lagrange1(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, float x);

inline void CGPointSet(CGPoint *v, float x, float y);
inline void f1(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, float d, CGPoint *o1, CGPoint *o2);
inline void f2(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, float d, CGPoint *o1, CGPoint *o2);

@interface CCBlade : CCNode {
    list<CGPoint> path;
    unsigned int pointLimit;
    int count;
    CGPoint vertices[2*POINT_LIMIT + 5];
    CGPoint coordinates[2*POINT_LIMIT + 5];
    BOOL reset;
@protected
    CCTexture2D *_texture;  
    float width;
}
@property unsigned int pointLimit;
@property(retain) CCTexture2D *texture;
@property float width;
- (void) push:(CGPoint) v;
- (void) pop;
- (void) clear;
- (void) reset;
- (void) dim:(BOOL) dim;
@end
```

Comment: Error message: "List: no such file or directory exists"

Comment: i've tried earlier version of cocos2d. but the same problem. maybe is the project setting or xcode 4 setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but true, the solution to fix the compile error is simply to rename any files that `#import` that header file to have `.mm` file extension. Please give it a try ;)

Comment: i've tried that out. but still failed. the file include(not import) the list is .h file.

Comment: @Fish vs Birds you need to rename all .m files that include/import the .h file ...

Comment: but the file that import the CCBlade.h file is only CCBlade.m and TouchTrailLayer.h file. i've changed CCBlade.m to .mm, but still the same problem. Can i send you my project?

Comment: Well, i've changed All the .m files in my project to .mm files. it works now. just curious, but why?

Comment: @Fish vs Birds .mm file extension tells the compiler to compile the files as Objective-C++ rather than Objective-C. I guess the compiler can only detect the correct STL path in C++ mode ..